# Error cannot resolve symbol loadanimation

Tags: animationutils

This code is work in eclipse for Android 4.1 
But  in Android studio  for Android 5.1 i have this error: cannot resolve symbol 'loadanimation '

I import everything, clean project, rebuild, restart. 
  why is not working? Please help

This is my code:

```
Animation anim = new AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.This, R.anim.anim)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.This, R.anim.anim);`

Method is already static, so remove the new keyword.